# refresh dataSource after update or add

Tags: angular, angular-material, datasource

I have a project built in angular Material and I need to modify it.

As I'm new in angular, I need your support to fix my issue.

I have one component that has multi-templated and generates a page for each template, the mission of this component is to view the data and add or update it.

My issue when Adding or updating a record "which works fine without issue" is that the data source didn't refresh, and I must refresh the page manually to see the new/updated data.

**My component:**

```
import { AfterViewInit, ChangeDetectorRef, Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { ActivatedRoute, ParamMap } from '@angular/router';
import { exhaustMap, filter, map, Observable, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { DictionaryTemplate } from 'src/app/app-models/dictionary';
import { ConfirmService } from 'src/app/app-services/confirm.service';
import { DeviceService } from 'src/app/app-services/device.service';
import { DictionaryService } from 'src/app/app-services/dictionary.service';
import LanguageService from 'src/app/app-services/language.service';
import {MatSort} from '@angular/material/sort';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-admin-dictionary',
  templateUrl: './admin-dictionary.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./admin-dictionary.component.scss']
})
export class AdminDictionaryComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  dictionaryName: string | null = '';
  isHandset = this.deviceService.isHandset$;
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();
  language$ = this.languageService.currentLanguage$;
  template!: DictionaryTemplate | null;
  columns = ['Id', 'Name', 'Description'];
  selected!: any;
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private dictionaryService: DictionaryService,
              private deviceService: DeviceService,
              private languageService: LanguageService,
              private confirm: ConfirmService,
              private changeDetectorRefs: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.url.pipe(
      map(x => x[0].path),
      tap(name => {
        this.template = this.dictionaryService.getDictionaryTemplate(name!);
         if(this.template?.haveParent) {
          this.columns.push(this.template?.parentLabel!)
        }
        if(this.template?.haveNumberProperty) {
          this.columns.push(this.template?.numberPropertyName!)
        }
      }),
      switchMap(() => this.template?.data!)
    ).subscribe(data =>
      {
         this.dataSource.data = data!;
       //  this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
      }
    );
  }
 
 
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.dataSource.sortingDataAccessor = (item: any, property) => {
      switch(property) {
        case 'Name': if(this.languageService.currentLanguage === 'ar') {
          return item['NameArabic'];
        } else {
          return item['NameEnglish'];
        }
        case this.template?.parentLabel!: if(this.languageService.currentLanguage === 'ar') {
          return item['ParentNameArabic'];
        } else {
          return item['ParentNameEnglish'];
        }
        default: return item[property];
      }
    }
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

  save() {
    if(this.template?.frm.invalid) {
      return;
    }
     
    if(!this.selected) {
      this.confirm.open({Type: 'add'}).pipe(
        filter(x => x),
        exhaustMap(() => this.dictionaryService.httpAddDictionary(this.template?.urlName!, this.template?.frm.value))
      ).subscribe(
        y => {
          if(y) this.template?.frm.reset();
         }
      );
     } else {
      this.confirm.open({Type: 'update'}).pipe(
        filter(x => x),
        exhaustMap(() => this.dictionaryService.httpEditDictionary(this.template?.urlName!, this.template?.frm.value) )
         
      ).subscribe(
        y => { 
             if(y) this.template?.frm.reset();
            }
          );
     }

  }
 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

why are you using filter? your filter is doing nothing,
remove tools that that aren't been used.

Read about exhaustMap() I think that you are using this tool in a bad way. You are using pipe() but you are not transfom this.confirm.open response.

```
this.confirm.open({Type: 'update'}).subscribe(
        y => { 
             if(y) this.template?.frm.reset();
            },
        () => this.dictionaryService.httpEditDictionary(this.template?.urlName!, this.template?.frm.value)
          );
```

Put you second request into "complete" section instead.

**The two request are not depending each from other**. Even better, you can remove your secod request from the first, example:

```
this.confirm.open({Type: 'update'})
.subscribe(y => if(y) this.template?.frm.reset();

this.dictionaryService.httpEditDictionary(this.template?.urlName!, this.template?.frm.value)
```

Split functuality that are not releted. Read about "Object Programing Paradigm"

Use the correct tool for the indicated problem

Are you print data in console.log? What is the print in console?:

```
.subscribe(data =>
      {
         this.dataSource.data = data!;
       //  this.changeDetectorRefs.detectChanges();
      }
```